# Securing API calls using Security Manager

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have an application which has certain utility methods in one of util class which supports certain DB operation including read/write/delete.

I now need to make sure that calls to these APIs can only be from trusted source with in the application.

Currently it seem to be possible that anyone can write a main program on the server itself and keep the "util" jar in class path along with other dependencies and is able execute certain DB operations by making call to the util class methods.

Browsing on the internet it seems Security Manager could be of some help but there is hardly any documentation present.
Requesting all to share there views and provide ways to deal with this security issue.

Comment: This can never be made secure when people have access to the server and the dependencies. Even if you have your util jar completely locked up, a malicious user can just try to retrieve the connection settings for the database connection (which are read write) and run the sql himself.

Comment: @Janoz That might be the case when the DB user/pass are in clear format. But I have it in encrypted format and only application logic can be simply decrypt that...to which i need to find a way to stop unauthorized access.

Comment: If that application logic is stored in the accessible jar then it is just as accessible as storing it in plain text. As long as people have the same execution rights on the server as your application then your problem is impossible to solve.